# Print button disabled in OpenGeo Suite?

Tags: printing, boundless-suite

Print button is disabled in Free version of OpenGeo Suite 4.02. In versions 3.x OGS, Community Edition, Print button was always enabled.

Does anyone know why?

---

I've almost decided to go back to version 3.1.

Is there any "what's new" list for 4.02 vs 3.1, but not in modules, maybe with restrictions?

I am asking are there more surprises in that new Boundless OGS?

I was very satisfied with CE releases of OGS 2.x and .3.x but in 4.x (with new brand).

Answer (score 2):

You need to manually install the GeoServer print (printing plugin) community extension from (it is not part of OpenGeo Suite):

http://ares.boundlessgeo.com/geoserver/2.4.x/community-latest/